Changing the structure of a DataFrame in Python from row level to column level
I have a DataFrame like below
name     Type      value
==================================
AAA       1       Increase  
AAA       2       Decrease
AAA       3       Neutral

I would like to convert the structure of the DF to something like below
name     Type1       Type2     Type3
==================================================
AAA     Increase   Decrease    Neutral

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,

Use pivot: df.pivot(index='name', columns='Type', values='value') and after that rename the columns to add Type in their name.

Does this answer your question? How to pivot a dataframe in Pandas?
